# Integrate External javascript SDK into Dynamcis crm 2016

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

This is all new to me. I know Dynamics CRM developing more customised forms etc, you will use the Visual Studio. Also within Visual studio you can create plugins, solutions etc.

I'm more inclined to the web resources. what I have done so far, is just to upload HTML within which has an API to call a map service LIKE google but in this case its ESRI maps as a web resource into one of the Dynamics forms. This creates my map within the specified form.

This is not however the ideal way to do this, as it will mean going to every form to load HTML.
Now ESRI has a JavaScript SDK which I would imagine, I can load into Dynamics as an external plugin to have access to ESRI javascript Library.
This is where I'm stuck at the moment.

Could anyone point me to how to install an external library into dynamics visual studio?

Also, is there a way of avoiding not having to manually add html as a web resource into every forms in Dynamics?

Comment: This is not clear. What's the problem you are facing ?

Answer (score 0):

You can upload the 3rd party JavaScript library as a web resource of type Script (JScript).

You can create the HTML resource once and reference it on all the forms, but yes, you do need to add it to each form initially.